# Getting NZEC in Java for PARTSUM on SPOJ

Tags: java, runtime-error

Array `T[]` has been used to store the sum of all possible contiguous combinations. And at each step, I am checking whether it is atleast `k` or not and that value is stored in the variable `val`. Below is the Java Code:

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

class Codechef {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws java.lang.Exception {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        long t = sc.nextLong();
        while (t > 0) {
            int n = sc.nextInt();
            long k = sc.nextLong();
            long p = sc.nextLong();
            long a[] = new long[n];
            long T[] = new long[((n * (n + 1)) / 2)];
            Arrays.fill(T, -1);
            long sum = 0, x = 0, val = p, f = 0;
            int i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
                a[i] = sc.nextLong();
                sum = sum + a[i];
                x = sum % p;
                T[i] = x;
                if (T[i] == k)
                    f = 1;
                else if (T[i] > k && T[i] < val)
                    val = T[i];
            }
            if (f != 1) {
                for (int j = i - 1; j > 0; j--) {
                    for (int m = 0; m < j; m++) {
                        x = T[j] - T[m];
                        if (x < 0)
                            x += p;
                        T[i] = x;
                        if (T[i] == k) {
                            f = 1;
                            break;
                        }
                        else if (T[i] > k && T[i] < val)
                            val = T[i];
                        i++;
                    }
                    if (f == 1)
                        break;
                }
            }
            if (f == 1)
                System.out.println(k);
            else
                System.out.println(val);
            t--;
        }
    }
}
```

The above is the code for [PARTSUM- Partial Sums](http://www.spoj.com/problems/PARTSUM/) on SPOJ. What could be the possible error?

Previously I was getting **Runtime error NZEC** on submit. Now that has been corrected and now I am getting **TLE**. Any optimization?

Comment: try running it on your own computer and see what error-message you get. Without a proper stacktrace there isn't much we can do.

Comment: In your nested for loops:  `T[i] = x;`. Last value of `i` was `n`. So this will throw you IndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: I already tried with many testcases, it runs correctly. Maybe I could get the correct one in Java. @Paul

Comment: No @RafiduzzamanSonnet because the length of `T[]` is not `n`